# Why is the optional binding not working

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is a question about **why** my code is not working, not about **how** to do something, that's why I didn't provide you with a data, but if you want, i can give you, but the data will be my *relatively small* ontology.

this is my code

```
OPTIONAL
      { 

    VALUES ?user { rs:ania }
        ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                  rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                  rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass .

        ?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass .

        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched  ?weightMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch  ?weightNotMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch  true
            BIND(1 AS ?skip_)
          }
      bind(if (bound(?skip_) && (not EXISTS {?user a ?userClass}) , ?skip_, 0) as ?skip1)


    values (?defaultUserMatched ?defaultUserNotMatched) {(1 0.5)}
        BIND(if(EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }, coalesce(?weightMatched, ?defaultUserMatched), coalesce(?weightNotMatched, ?defaultUserNotMatched)) AS ?weight)


      }
    values ?defaultNoUserContext {1}
    BIND(if(bound(?skip1), ?skip1, 0) as ?skip)
    BIND(if(bound(?weight), ?weight, ?defaultNoUserContext) AS ?userContextWeight)

  }
```

this code is just a block in my real query, there is another block that brings the `?item` variable.

as you see, my code has `?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass` , but one of the bindings for `?item` is not from the type of `?itemClass` so the whole optional will not execute (for that binding), so when we go out of the optional, there is this line

```
BIND(if(bound(?weight), ?weight, ?defaultNoUserContext) AS ?userContextWeight)
```

the `if` part will give `false` so the `?userContextWeight` should be bound to `?defaultNoUserContext`. However, my code doesn't produce anything (any value at all) to these items . do you know why please?

again if you need data, i am more than welcome to give you, thanks

#### Update

Now I see better, what i want is:

even if the item doesn't belong to the `?itemClass`, i need to give a default value for the `?userContextWeight`.

look at the update

```
 OPTIONAL
      { 
     VALUES ?user { rs:ania }

        ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                  rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                  rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass .

    bind (if (  exists {?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass .}, true , false) as ?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass)

    OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched  ?weightMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch  ?weightNotMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch  true
            BIND(1 AS ?skip_)
          }
      bind(if (bound(?skip_) && (not EXISTS {?user a ?userClass}) , ?skip_, 0) as ?skip1)


    values (?defaultUserMatched ?defaultUserNotMatched) {(1 0.5)}
        BIND(if(EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }, coalesce(?weightMatched, ?defaultUserMatched), coalesce(?weightNotMatched, ?defaultUserNotMatched)) AS ?weight)
      }
    values ?defaultNoUserContext {1}
    BIND(if(bound(?skip1), ?skip1, 0) as ?skip)

  BIND( if ( !?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass , ?defaultNoUserContext ,if(bound(?weight), ?weight, ?defaultNoUserContext)) AS ?userContextWeight)

  }
```

in the update, i check if the item belongs to the class or not using this `bind`

```
 bind (if (  exists {?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass .}, true , false) as ?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass)
```

and then outside the `optional` i do this

```
BIND( if ( !?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass , ?defaultNoUserContext ,if(bound(?weight), ?weight, ?defaultNoUserContext)) AS ?userContextWeight)
```

my problem is the value of `?userContextWeight` when the item doesn't belong to the class is `?weightNotMatched`, but it should be `?defaultNoUserContext` (look again at the last binding please)

any idea please?

#### Update 2

by `!?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass` I mean the normal boolean **not** that we study in algebra, maybe here it is not the same as there? this could be the problem?

#### Update 3

I see that this

```
 bind (if ( exists {?item  a  ?itemClass }, true , false) as ?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass)
```

always gives `true` to `doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass` even though that is not correct, for a specific `item`, it is not from the `itemClass`.

**now i am sure that the problem is here, because i printed the value of the `doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass` and it is always true** but that is not correct, we are close, so just solving this will solve the question

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The outermost optional includes a non-optional "?item rdf:type ?itemClass .", so if the item doesn't have the right type, then the entire outermost optional doesn't match. If you want the item class to be optional within the optional, you'd need to write it that way.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor your comment was helpful, i can see something new now, i am trying myself and i iwll be back to you

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i updated my quesiton, i think we are close of the solution, it is just a small matter, could you check the update please ? (i am ready if the code is not clear to clear for you)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i've just updated my question, it sounds like the first `if` statement in the last `bind` statement is never giving true.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I did a third update, could you check please ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor now I printed the value of `doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass` and it is always true, though i make a question to check if the `?item` is from `?itemClass` and it is not, here is the problem, would you like to give you my ontology? ( you don't wnat to see it at all, you just can test the query), now i have proof that the problem is in binding for doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass

Comment: I'm not sure what bindings would be in place when you're checking the `exists { ?item a ?itemClass }`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i can see the binding for the ?item and ?itemClass because I do select for them, and 10000% the item is NOT from the itemClass

Comment: Yes, I understand that part.  What I'm saying is that I'm not sure whether those bindings are in scope during the `bind(exists { ... }, ..`.  The bind might only be checking whether *some* item belongs to ?itemClass. If the value of ?item isn't set yet, it's just checking whether *something* belongs to ?itemClass, which is probably true.

Comment: By the way, I *think* you can just do `bind(exists { ... } as ...)`;  I don't think that you need the `if` there.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor now i tried bind without if, and the same result

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor here is the data http://www.mediafire.com/download/z28zies1blo9bww/rs.ttl and here is the query http://www.mediafire.com/download/7hvq2e48lvv2vzx/query.sparql could you check please ?

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i am checking thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is big enough that I'm having a very hard time making sense of it, but my best guess is that you're running into a situation where your **exists** expression doesn't have all the variables bound that you need to make it test what you want it to test.  Here's some *very simple* data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:s a :D .
:t a :E .
```

Now, take a look at this query and the results:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select * where {
  #-- Find an individual ?a and (one of)
  #-- the classes that it belongs to.
  ?a a ?aClass .

  optional {
    #-- Find an individual ?b and (one of)
    #-- the classes that it belongs to.
    ?b a ?bClass .

    #-- And bind ?isCommonClass to true or
    #-- false, to indicate whether ?b is
    #-- also an element of ?aClass.
    bind(exists{?b a ?aClass} as ?isCommonClass)
  }
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------
| a  | aClass | b  | bClass | isCommonClass |
=============================================
| :s | :D     | :s | :D     | true          |
| :s | :D     | :t | :E     | true          |
| :t | :E     | :s | :D     | true          |
| :t | :E     | :t | :E     | true          |
---------------------------------------------
```

?isCommonClass is always true, even though it seems like it should be true when ?a and ?b are the same, and false otherwise.  I *think* that what's happening here is that the **bind** gets evaluated in a context where either ?b or ?aClass isn't set yet, so the **exists** is actually checking for something more general.  We can test this by moving the **bind** outside of the **optional**:

```sql
select * where {
  ?a a ?aClass .

  optional {
    ?b a ?bClass .
  }

  bind(exists{?b a ?aClass} as ?isCommonClass)
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------
| a  | aClass | b  | bClass | isCommonClass |
=============================================
| :s | :D     | :s | :D     | true          |
| :s | :D     | :t | :E     | false         |
| :t | :E     | :s | :D     | false         |
| :t | :E     | :t | :E     | true          |
---------------------------------------------
```

Here, we get the results we'd expect, with ?isCommonClass being true exactly when ?a and ?b are the same.

The query snippet in the question doesn't provide enough to be sure that this is what's happening, and the query you provided in the comments is too big for anyone else to check, but this *seems* like a very good candidate for what's going on in your situation.

Comment: the query is big i know, but if you format, you see that it is just two parts, the first one gives the items and the second one check if these items have a context, your answer is logic but i need to figure out how to test it on my case, let me try please

Comment: i am not sure if that is the reason or not, because if you execute the query on the data i provided (even without knowing anything about the query or the data) you can see the binding, i did select for the item and the itemClass and both are set, and as you see the itemClass is before the bind and the item is the same as well

Comment: oooops i did bind (?item as ?www) and select ?www but all empty, that explains what's going on, omg :( :( :(

Comment: @Ania When I apply this approach to your query, I get three rows in the result, one with false, and three with true, which is different from your "whatTheF*ckIsYourValue" variable, which was four trues.  So I think that the issue described in this answer probably applies to your query, too.

Comment: I would need to ask another better question for that then, it is a different problem , thank you, you are the one

Comment: one with what ? you should get 4 not 3

Comment: do you mean to get the bind out of the optional ? that is the soluiton ?

Comment: @AniaDavid I have no idea what this query is supposed to return, and I don't have a way of knowing, so I have no idea whether it's a solution.

Comment: yes you meant that :) I tested now it is working like a charm in a sunny spring, thank you, if Beethoven is the symphony guy, and Verdi is the Opera guy, You are the SPARQL guy

Comment: @AniaDavid But have a look at https://gist.github.com/tayloj/30202bbd746c8da8bbd09ddfa7c6051a . The lines (10 and 137) in the query that I changed are marked with (***).  The last two columns in the output are different, for the same reasons demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: oh i just saw your comment last one

Comment: yes exactly that, i just moved the `bind (if ( exists {?item  a  ?itemClass }, true , false) as ?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass)` out of the optional right before `values ?defaultNoUserContext {1}` and i got correct results. appreciate it really so much

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You can check the query algebra at http://sparql.org/validate/query, and you're right, the BIND is evaluated first.

Comment: @aksw thanks!  That's the kind of thing that I need to confirm (or deny) my suspicion.